# Why does SqlDataReader seem to modify the type of its data?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldatareader

This question is a next step after [this DBA related question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/298307).

I now have following C# code, based on the variables`SqlCommand sqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader sqlDataReader`.

I am running this piece of code:

```
// What's the max difference of two "Own_Table" tupples for "Field_Name" column?
sqlCommand.CommandText = $"SELECT MAX(val - lag_value) FROM " + 
                         $" (SELECT t.{Field_Name} AS val,LAG(t.{Field_Name}) " +
                         $"    OVER(ORDER BY t.{Field_Name}) as lag_value " +
                         $"  FROM {Own_Table} t) AS tmp " +
                         $"WHERE lag_value IS NOT NULL";
sqlCommand.Parameters.Clear();
sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
long max_value = 0;
while (sqlDataReader.Read())
{
    max_value = sqlDataReader.GetInt32(0); <== sometimes NOK
}
```

For one particular field, this seems to go wrong: for the field `Id` the mentioned line of source code generates a `System.InvalidCastException`, mentioning `Specific cast is not valid.`.

This is correct, because in the immediate window, I can see following result:

```
? sqlDataReader.GetFieldType(0).ToString()
"System.Int64"
```

However, the `DataType` in the corresponding DataTable's column seems to be `System.Int32`, as you can see from following immediate window's excerpt (`dt_main` being the `DataTable` and `i` meaning the index of the corresponding column):

```
? dt_main.Columns[i].DataType
{Name = "Int32" FullName = "System.Int32"}
```

On a previous column with same `DataType`, everything was working fine.

So now my question: how is it possible that a query resulton a `System.Int32` column can suddenly decide to have `System.Int64` as a datatype, and what's the best way to handle this? (I have already tried replacing all `sqlDataReader.GetInt32()` by `sqlDataReader.GetInt64()` but this also failed).

The `DataTable dt_main`'s structure is retrieve from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` as follows:

```
sqlCommand.CommandText = 
  "SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS " + 
  "WHERE TABLE_NAME = @selectedItem";
sqlCommand.Parameters.Clear();
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("selectedItem", cmb_Table_Names.SelectedItem);
// cmb_Table_Names contains all table names.
sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

while (sqlDataReader.Read()) // Get the names of all the columns
{
    string tmp_ColName = sqlDataReader.GetString(0);
    string tmp_ColDataType = sqlDataReader.GetString(1);
    Type T = typeof(string);
    switch (tmp_ColDataType)
    { 
        case "int": case "bigint": case "tinyint": case "smallint":
            T = typeof(int);
            break;
        case "bit":
            T = typeof(bool);
            break;
        case "varchar": case "datetime": case "text":
            T = typeof(string);
            break;
        default: 
            T = typeof(string);
            break;
    }
    dt_main.Columns.Add(tmp_ColName,T);
```

Comment: The obvious reason for a mismatch would be if `i` was *not* equal to `0`, since one of your code snippets hard-codes the column ordinal, and the other doesn't.

Comment: @mjwills: I've adapted my question accordingly.

Comment: What exact query causes the issue?  Please show us the `CREATE TABLE` for that exact table.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: the `i` (as in column number `i`) and the fixed number 0 are not linked: I'm looking into every column (hence the counter `i`) and for each of those I'm running the "SELECT MAX ..." for seeing the maximum difference of values inside that one column.

Comment: @jdweng There is literally no chance that is making a difference here. The compiler option in no way changes how ADO.NET works. It just doesn't. I am not sure where you got that idea from, but it isn't true. It is _almost certain_ the OP is querying a table with a bigint column. But until they share the `CREATE TABLE` there is no way to be sure.

Comment: @mjwills : If the databaseis 32 bits and compiler is 64 bits wouldn't you get a 64 bit result?

Comment: @jdweng No. You won't. Why do you think you would?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code analyzing the schema information is broken. Here:

```
    case "int": case "bigint": case "tinyint": case "smallint":
        T = typeof(int);
```

you assume that the SQL Server types `int`, `bigint`, `tinyint` and `smallint` all map to the C# type `int` (i.e., the .NET Framework type `Int32`).

This is incorrect. `bigint`, for example, corresponds to C#'s `long`, i.e., .NET Frameworks's `Int64`.

You can use the following MSDN entry to find the correct mappings:

- [ADO.NET: SQL Server Data Type Mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings)